# Input validation through AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have the following AJAX in my **index.php**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.buttono').click(load);
 });

 function load() {
     $.ajax({
         url: 'http://localhost/Generator/js/ajaxRequest.php'
     }).done(function(data) {
         $('#content').append(data);
     });
 }
```

HTML (part of **index.php**):

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <input type="text" name="input">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="buttono" value="Convert">
</form>
<div id='content'></div>
```

And in my **ajaxRequest.php** I have the following PHP snippet:

```
if ($_POST['input'] == 'dog') {
    echo 'Status 1';
} else if ($_POST['input'] == 'cat') {
    echo 'Status 2';
}
```

How can I perform the PHP check through AJAX? So that if I click the submit button and have typed 'dog', to return the string *Status 1*?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to submit the form and then get the response, but with ajax?

Comment: Yes. And validate the POST.

Answer (score 2):

Well what I see in your code is that:

first you have not specified your request method,

second you have not set $_POST['dog']

I would have gone with this ajax:

```
$.ajax({
  type : "POST",
  url : 'to/url',
  data : { input : $("input[name='input']").val() },
  success :  function(data){
    // do whatever you like
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is make the user fill out the form and then instead of clicking a `type="submit"` button just make them click a regular button. Then when that person clicks the regular button submit. You can do this by:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" id="type"/>
    <button id="submit">Sumbit</button>
</form>


<!-- JS -->
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit').click(onSubmitClicked);
});

function onSubmitClicked(){
    var data = {
        "input": $('#type').val()
    };

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "url/To/Your/Form/Action",
      data: data,
      success: success
    });

    function success(data){
        if(data == 'status 1'){
           //Do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing shows up. What's more, the page is refreshing.

Comment: Can you paste the code into a JSfiddle, I have a feeling you are still clicking your original submit button.

Comment: I can't figure how JSfiddle is rendering AJAX requests. I did a full copy/paste of your code though.

Comment: Try my solution on your webpage, **NOT** JSFiddle. JSFiddle does not work normally with this kind of stuff because of the way it is displaying your content.

Comment: As I said, nothing shows up. Here's a full copy/paste http://pastebin.com/EwHAr28R

Comment: Ahh, I thought you copy and pasted into JSfiddle. Did you change the url?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

in you php file:

```
$res = array();

if ($_POST['input'] == 'dog') {
    $res['status'] = '1';
} elseif ($_POST['input'] == 'cat') {
    $res['status'] = '2';
}

echo json_encode($res);
```

Then in your jquery:

```
function load(){
    $.ajax({
         type : "POST",
         data : { input : $("input[name='input']").val() }, 
         url:'http://localhost/Generator/js/ajaxRequest.php'
    }).done(function(data){
        $('#content').append(data.status);
    });

}
```

Comment: You have 2 `url` params in the ajax request in your code.